# JQuery ajax data option "key" value cannot be created from a passed variable, how can I do this?

Tags: jquery

The following works perfectly until I try to replace the hard coded "service_id" with the passed string variable id_name.

Is there a way to pass a variable into this part of the options?, If so, how be it?

Working version:

```
function deleteRecord(id)
{
$.ajax({
  'url': url_root+'admin/index',
  'type': 'POST',
  'data': {"service_id" : id,
          'ajax_name': 'services_list_table'
          },
  'dataType': 'json',
  'success': function(data)
        {
            $("#ajax_services_table").html(data.html);
        }
    });
}
```

Not working version (passing in the "service_id" as a variable)

```
function deleteRecord(id,id_name)
{
    $.ajax({
      'url': url_root+'admin/index',
      'type': 'POST',
      'data': {id_name : id,
              'ajax_name': 'services_list_table'
              },
      'dataType': 'json',
      'success': function(data)
            {
                $("#ajax_services_table").html(data.html);
            }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need to do...

```
var data = { 'ajax_name': 'services_list_table' };

data[id_name] = id;
```

Then pass `data` to `data` of your `$.ajax()`.